# Can --skip-broken parameter in yum command uninstall existing packages installed in machine

Tags: yum

As per the document https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html, following is the description for --skip-broken parameter:

--skip-broken
Resolve depsolve problems by removing packages that are
causing problems from the transaction.  It is an alias for
the strict configuration option with value False.
Additionally, with the enable and disable module
subcommands it allows one to perform an action even in
case of broken modular dependencies.

Can using this parameter in yum command uninstall existing packages in the machine or it does only skip some input packages in the yum install command?

Comment: This should be read as "by removing packages [...] from the transaction", not as "by removing packages [from installed packages]".