# Can --fix-broken parameter in apt-get command uninstall existing packages installed in machine

Tags: apt

As per the document https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get, following is the description for --fix-broken parameter:

-f, --fix-broken
Fix. Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. Any package(s) that are specified must completely correct the problem. This option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention. Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations.
Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.

**Can using this parameter in apt-get command uninstall existing packages in the machine or it does only skip some input packages in the apt-get command?**

I have asked similar query for yum command in the post: [Can --skip-broken parameter in yum command uninstall existing packages installed in machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766008/can-skip-broken-parameter-in-yum-command-uninstall-existing-packages-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `--fix-broken` can remove packages which are currently installed.